# Studies demonstrating viremia in Alzheimer's disease

Tags: alzheimers, herpes-simplex

A good deal of research indicates that viruses (particularly, HSV-1 and HHV-6A) play a role in Late-Onset Alzheimer's Disease (Readhead, 2018; Itzhaki, 2021). Can someone point me to some studies measuring virus particles in the blood or CSF in Alzheimer's? Especially compared to virus particles in the blood or CSF of a control population. I haven't been able to find any.

Readhead, 2018: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6551233/

Itzhaki, 2021: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34205498/

Comment: Maybe CSF and blood aren't where they lurk. Varicella is a good example. You'll find antibodies to varicella in the blood of someone who's had chicken pox, but you won't find virus particles. And yet, as we know from shingles, the virus is still present.